# Gradle project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath always blank

Tags: plugins, configuration, runtime, gradle, classpath

I'm writing a Gradle plugin to generate Java code from WSDL. Problem is, my task does not find the Java class I'm trying to execute and blows up at runtime with a ClassNotFoundException even though the necessary jar is listed as a compile dependency. I'm using `project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` but have tried compileClasspath, adding a build script section to the build file, using configurations.runtime, all to no avail. Note that my project has no Java src code, just Groovy.

Any ideas? The task, a unit test and the build file can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/abhijitsarkar/8432347

*c.f.: cross posted on the Gradle forum*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that because my plugin uses `project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`, the client needs to declare the dependencies with runtime scope. It is not enough to have the dependencies declared in the plugin project only.